# Can echo a sql query result but can't use as variable in mailto()

Tags: php, sql, email

I am a php newbie, but I'm trying to learn and I have been trying to fix this issue for over a week with loads of variations tried.

Short story  - I query a db for an email address that I want to use in a form mail() function. I can echo the email on the page (just to check I'm querying OK).. but no email is sent. I've read all the php tutorial pages and hundreds of forums posts, I think that my issue is that $cemail is an object not a string?

On the mail() function I have 2 lines, one using the $cemail and one going to a fixed address. I receive the fixed address email, so I know the form is working.

The post form send verification reports an empty variable though - :(

Your message was sent to us successfully. ><

```
            // retrieve link data

            $userid = $_GET['userid'];

            // connect to DB

            $con=mysqli_connect("xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx");

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM wp_participants_database WHERE id = '$userid'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $cemail = $row['email']; 


            {
            echo  $cemail;
            }

......

                mail($cemail,$subject,$emailbody,$headers);
    mail("example@email.com",$subject,$emailbody,$headers);



            ?>
            <div>
                <p class="alert alert-success"><?php _e('Your message was sent to us successfully. >' . $cemail .'<', _THEME); ?></p>
```

This is a site I'm creating for the wife... and I've spent many hours banging my head against this already - any help is much appreciated! :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you point to what doesn't work?

Comment: What is inside `$cemail`?  Please show us what `var_dump( $cemail )` gives.

Comment: please check this query in phpmyadmin `SELECT email FROM wp_participants_database WHERE id ='$userid'`

Comment: is your database connection proper? definitely an error over there..

Comment: where do you set $userid?

Comment: Sorry - muppet I am. I get userid from a GET. I'm echoing the $cemail which displays the right email on the page just for diagnosing. After I complete the form, however, I have an extra print for diagnosis and that reports that the $cemail variabel is empty. I've edited the code above to add those lines in.

Comment: ahh nice call on vardump... I get string(21) "email@email.com" (i.e. the correct email). OK... interesting it is a string